# Efecto swipe al cerrar fragmento

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un *fragment* que muestro con un botón. Lo que quiero hacer es que para cerrarlo y pasar a la actividad desde donde lo llame, osea volver atrás, se pueda hacer usando *swipe* desde el lado izquierdo.

He buscado pero solo encuentro ejemplos con *viewPager* y pestañas, pero eso no me sirve porque desde la actividad principal no tiene que hacerse ese efecto.

https://youtu.be/eVcSCWetnTA

Ese vídeo más o menos muestra lo que quiero lograr.

Comment: Es mas o menos extenso para responder. Por ahora solo puedo indicarte que se pueden definir animaciones para las transiciones de las Activities. Quizá la documentación oficial de Android te sirva para hacerte una idea de como se hace. https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: Hola encontré esto https://github.com/enbandari/SwipeFinishableActivity pero no se como agregarlo a mi proyecto x.x me podrías decir como?